# Explore Influence of features on titanic dataset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am currently working with the famous titanic dataset from Kaggle. Now I want to explore the influence on different features on the chance of survival. I use the random fores classifier for an accuracy score output.

I want to know whether people with sibling have a bigger chance of survival than people without. I could slice my dataset into one with siblings and one without.

However these might probably not be comparable either because of the size or e.g. that people with sibblings are more often female. The comparison is distorted.

How can I account for that and answer my question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're using already, but SKLearn has a feature importance function that uses random forests to do something like what you're saying.

For your question about the survival of those with siblings, you need to think of it is an experiment with controls. Compare the survival rate of females with siblings vs. the rate for all those with siblings.

Answer (score 0):

While random forest will probably give the most accurate answers, it's difficult to interpret.

I'm just making a start on the titanic data set - see you on Kaggle :-)

I'm going to start with some exploratory analysis.

This plot indicates that there is some connection between number of siblings & chance of survival, taking sex into account.

[image: plot]